# ¿Existe alguna comunidad dentro de Stack Exchange en la cual se base en opiniones?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange

Varias veces me he encontrado con que realizo una pregunta en la cual espero una respuesta formal por parte de la comunidad, pero a muchos de los usuarios les parece una pregunta basada en opiniones o así la califica la comunidad y a la final la pregunta es cerrada.

A veces quisiera plantear preguntas en las cuales pueda tener una segunda opinión por parte de algún usuario experimentado de la comunidad. No creo ser el unico usuario el cual quiera proponer este tipo de preguntas.

**Si existe una comunidad para proponer este tipo de preguntas, ¿cuál es?**

**Y si no existe, ¿por que?**

Comment: ¿ Bajo que criterios se puede *puntuar* una opinión ? ¿ Como decides *aceptar* una opinión ?

Comment: Existen muchos tipos de preguntas *basadas en opiniones* por lo que mi duda es; ¿qué tipo de pregunta es? ¿podrias mostrar un ejemplo? Hay sitios que aceptan preguntas que en SOen son consideradas en *basadas en opiniones*

Comment: @eyllanesc Por ejemplo, en esta [pregunta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/420981/what-is-the-best-way-to-organize-the-folders-and-files-in-my-web-project) quería obtener una opinión por parte de algún usuario experimentado de la comunidad a lo que se califico como una pregunta basada en opiniones.

Comment: para eso es el chat y por ello el privilegio si quieres participar te invito al [chat] puedes hablar de lo que quieras pero con respeto

Comment: @Trauma Se puede puntuar de la manera en que los demás usuarios estén de acuerdo con la opinión y/o compartan el mismo pensamiento.

Comment: @JohnDoe Para ese tipo de preguntas no existe ningun sitio que yo conozca

Comment: @eyllanesc Por lo mismo, por que no existe un sitio en el cual pueda obtener alguna opinión por parte de algún usuario

Comment: Y si varios usuarios estén de acuerdo, exactamente, ¿ Que significa ? Si tienes 2 opiniones, una con +5 y otra con +3, ¿ Que conclusión sacas ?

Comment: @JohnDoe Quien sabe pero si quieres proponer la creación de ese tipo de sitios es mejor que lo hagas en https://meta.stackexchange.com/ , quizas en el area51 haya algun sitio para ello: https://area51.stackexchange.com . Recuerda que el meta SOes esta para discutir sobre las preguntas y respuestas de SOes.

Comment: @Trauma Cuando exista este tipo de casos entraría yo como la persona que realizo la pregunta a marcar su respuesta (u opinión) como la mas acertada. Solo recuerda que aunque solicite una opinión no significa que este de acuerdo con todas o compartamos el mismo pensamiento,

Comment: @eyllanesc De acuerdo, con lo que me das a entender no existe un sitio en el cual pueda solicitar opiniones, posiblemente dentro del chat lo pueda hacer. Gracias y bonito día.

Comment: dependiendo de la pregunta que hagas puedes llegar a rasgar la norma y convertirla en una pregunta legible...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existen comunidades de todo tipo.

Lo que pasa, es que hay que encontrar la comunidad exacta para cada tipo de preguntas.

Cuando vas al tour de cada sitio, te dice que tipo de preguntas se admiten, y cuales no.

Tal vez, tu pregunta era basada en opiniones en ese sitio, pero en otro no.

Por ejemplo, el sitio [code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) se admiten ciertos tipos de preguntas basadas en opiniones.

Segun su [recorrido](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour):

> Best practices and design pattern usage

En este sitio se aceptan preguntas sobre patrones de diseño y mejores practicas, que aca suelen ser cerradas.

Lo mejor que podes hacer, es siempre chequear el recorrido. y si no, preguntar en el chat. Las preguntas que son opiniones, no van bien con el formato de este sitio, que busca preguntas y respuestas. Ademas, algunas de ellas, solamente le sirven a quien pregunta.

Answer (score 6):

Sí hay comunidades basadas en opiniones: [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com), por ejemplo. Lo que pasa es que no son opiniones del tipo comentario de ascensor, sino más bien opiniones fundamentadas.

Y esto me lleva al punto descrito aquí: las preguntas basadas en opiniones no pueden formularse, según las reglas de este sitio. Ahora bien, hay maneras y maneras de preguntar: siempre dicen que la mejor manera de tener respuestas de cosas de Linux es diciendo que no funciona y que es mejor en Windows; inmediatamente, aparecerá algún linuxero con una solución. En el caso de preguntas sobre programación, lo suyo es formular la pregunta de modo que sea respondible en base a criterios objetivos.

Es decir, preguntas así no serían válidas:

- ¿Por qué Vue.js es mejor que Angular?
- ¿Por qué Python 3 es mejor que Python 2?

Pero si las formulamos de forma algo diferente, con diferente enfoque, probablemente sí sean aceptadas:

- ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el uso de X en Vue.js y Angular?
- ¿Qué hace que Python 3 sea más rápido que Python 2 a la hora de ejecutar cálculos?

Por lo que te animo a plantear preguntas enfocándolas pensando en que las respuestas puedan ser cuantificables y medibles.

Comment: Espero que en algun futuro haya uno mismo pero en español